# Combining Java layout and xml

Tags: java, android, xml

I created a custom `RelativeLayout` and I want to populate it with a design from an xml file, is it possible?

My code:
This is the onCreate from my main activity

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(new CustomRelativeLayout(this));
    getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.three_items_list_row, null, false);
}
```

Comment: Consider adding your custom view from XML, its easier

Comment: How do I add it from xml? its custom for a reason, it has extra parameters and stuff so I need to define it in Java...

Answer (score 0):

Just call addView for your custom RelativeLayout instance,
I must say it not a very good coding because you add a Layout level

You need to modify your class to this:

```
class CustomRelativeLayout{
    public CustomRelativeLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle){
         super(context,attrs,defStyle);
         init();
    }

    public CustomRelativeLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs){
         super(context,attrs);
         init();
    }

    public CustomRelativeLayout(Context context){
         super(context);
         init();
    }
    private void init(){
         LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService( Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE );
         View v = inflatet.inflate(R.layout.three_items_list_row, this, false);
         addView(v);
    }
}
```

Comment: This answer is suggesting you call addView inside your custom RelativeLayout (probably inside the constructors) in order to add the layout you want to inflate from xml.